# is Adobe Air capable of converting a complex Flash game into iPad/android platform game?

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, cross-platform

I've recently heard about the converting feature of Adobe Air but how well does it work?
Does it emulate every bit of code a complex Flash game using tons of libraries outputs or should you expect a lot of work to go around if you were to convert one?

I'm thinking of making a complex cross-platform game but not sure which is better/easier, to use Flash and Adobe Air for its abundant game libraries, resources and faster development or to simply go with Java.

It Would really save lots of time if I can use Flash. Though, I can imagine it would also give me headaches to worry about all the time. Like what if adobe/apple stops supporting Flash or what if the converting feature won't work.

Any advice and any bit of information would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR works well on iOS in my experience although native apps will always perform better. I cant think of any aspects of Flash that wont work when converted to run on iOS.

Whether AIR performance is good enough really depends on the individual case - how gpu and cpu intensive the game is.

You have to consider the trade-off: use existing Flash skills to create a 'good' game quickly; or learn new skills to create a 'better' game slowly - is it worth spending weeks/months learning new skills to get a few extra percent of performance? Only you can decide that.

Regarding Adobes AIR support in the future; who knows - they dont have a great track record (think flash on mobile) - but i would suggest AIR will be around for at least the medium term, if not long-term.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried air iOS and seems like it converts the code well. Only issue is the performance though

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that "mobile" is not going anywhere and now is the best time to start learning Java for Android and/or Objective-C for iOS. Like PhoneGap, Flash mobile Apps don't give you complete access to the devices entire API/SDK options, even though what they do offer usually suffices. Flash is still a respectable tool but developing "native" gives you full control over your app's memory, device interaction, cutting edge APIs, etc ...

Depending on how optimized your action script 3 code is written, you may experience some performance issues vs utilizing native graphics libraries. I assume the latest version of AIR (I know Flash 11.2 and on included some nice graphic stuff) may address performance but haven't seen any benchmarks for AIR on mobile devices yet.

If you are hoping to go the AIR route, I'd say why not take a few days and try to port it over. If all else fails get a nice iOS or Android book and cuddle with it every night until you are confident you can recreate your App natively.